# Insert query with gettime() into SQL Server table using Python

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I am having an issue putting the below SQL query into Python :

```
insert into GERVERSION values (10, 'xxxxxxxx', 7, 4, 2, getdate(),'')
```

Note that in SQL , I have timestamp for the **getdate()** part

Can anyone please help me out with the right syntax to put this into work ?

Comment: Do you **really** have a column with datatype `TIMESTAMP` in SQL Server? That is **not** a column to hold date and time information in SQL Server; It's been renamed `ROWVERSION` because it really is a system-internal, binary version number of the row - it has nothing to do with date and time. Use `DATETIME2(n)` for handling date and time instead

Comment: Please post the DDL (`CREATE TABLE ...`)

Comment: getdate() it will give timestamp value. pls check you are inserting into correct column

Comment: Also: **what** issue do you have? Do you get an error message - if so, **what** error?

Comment: ... @marc_s, although the documentation states that `timestamp is the synonym for the rowversion data type`, it is the other way around, rowversion is a synonym for timestamp.The data type remains timestamp: `create table a(col rowversion);exec  sp_help 'a';drop table a;`  ... `select type_id('rowversion'), type_id('timestamp')`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO GERVERSION
SELECT 10, 'xxxxxxxx', 7, 4, 2, GETDATE(), '';
```

Comment: Tim - just out of curiosity - what's the benefit in your opinion to use the `INSERT INTO.. SELECT` approach over the `INSERT INTO .... VALUES ` one? Since the inserted values are all constants, variables or results of function calls like `GETDATE()`, I don't really see any advantage to this approach - am I missing something?

Comment: @marc_s Honestly I didn't even know that it were possible to have function calls inside a `VALUES` clause.  In some databases, it isn't allowed.

Comment: OK - I see your point - but yes, in SQL Server, calling a built-in function like `GETDATE()` (or preferably `SYSDATETIME()` these days) is in fact possible inside a `VALUES()` clause

Comment: @marc_s, correct . Using getdate() worked solved it . Thank you